# ¿Cómo listar todos los archivos de una carpeta usando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, python-2.x

Construyo un programa que requiere conocer los archivos del directorio de trabajo (*current working directory*). Por ello, hice el siguiente código, que busca y confirma la existencia del archivo de nombre `arq_buscado`:

```
def encontrar_arq(arq_buscado, camino):
   encontrado = False
   # lista_arq = ls(camino) #función que lista todos los archivos de la ruta
   for nome_arq in lista_arq:
       if nome_arq == arq_buscado:
           encontrado = True
   return encontrado
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener la lista de todos los archivos de una una carpeta en una lista de Python?

Comment: Cuando uso "ls" no me aparece solo la lista de los archivos, tambien me aparece datos de fecha, hora, volumen de la unidad, etc, necesito que con ese comando solo me aparezca el listado. Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Existen diferentes formas de obtener todos los archivos de un directorio. A continuación se muestran diferentes formas, todas ellas devuelven una lista al llamarlas así:

```python
lista_arq = ls(ruta)   # no especificar ruta para tomar el directorio actual
```

1. #### Mayor eficiencia con [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) - [python-3.5](/questions/tagged/python-3.5)

   Devuelve un **iterador** a [objetos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) que mantienen las propiedades de los archivos, haciéndolo más eficiente (por ejemplo, no necesita realizar una llamada al sistema adicional para ver si un objeto es un archivo o un directorio).

   ```python
   from os import scandir, getcwd

   def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
       return [arch.name for arch in scandir(ruta) if arch.is_file()]
   ```

   O si se quiere obtener la **ruta absoluta** de cada archivo:

   ```python
   from os import scandir, getcwd
   from os.path import abspath

   def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
       return [abspath(arch.path) for arch in scandir(ruta) if arch.is_file()]
   ```

2. #### Con la librería [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) y su clase principal [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) - [python-3.4](/questions/tagged/python-3.4)

   Ofrece mayor nivel de **consistencia** entre los diferentes sistemas operativos, sin la necesidad de referenciar directamente a [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), evitando también muchas llamadas al sistema.

   ```python
   from pathlib import Path

   def ls(ruta = Path.cwd()):
       return [arch.name for arch in Path(ruta).iterdir() if arch.is_file()]
   ```

   <sup>* gracias a [kikocorreoso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2816/kikocorreoso) por la referencia y su artículo de [joyitas](http://pybonacci.org/2016/05/18/joyitas-en-la-stdlib-pathlib/).</sup>

3. #### Listar todos los directorios y archivos con [`listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) - [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) y [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

   ```python
   from os import listdir

   def ls(ruta = '.'):
       return listdir(ruta)
   ```

   O sólo **archivos**:

   ```python
   from os import listdir
   from os.path import isfile, join

   def ls(ruta = '.'):
       return [arch for arch in listdir(ruta) if isfile(join(ruta, arch))]
   ```

4. #### Mayor control con [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) - [python-2.2](/questions/tagged/python-2.2) y [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

   Se pueden obtener sólo los archivos de forma más **compacta**:

   ```python
   from os import walk

   def ls(ruta = '.'):
       return next(walk(ruta))[2]
   ```

   O se puede tener mayor control si se quiere, obteniendo dos listas (**directorios y archivos**)

   ```python
   from os import walk

   def ls(ruta = '.'):
       dir, subdirs, archivos = next(walk(ruta))
       print("Actual: ", dir)
       print("Subdirectorios: ", subdirs)
       print("Archivos: ", archivos)
       return archivos
   ```

   Y si también se quiere obtener **los archivos de todos los subdirectorios**, permite iterar de la siguiente forma:

   ```python
   from os import walk, getcwd

   def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
       listaarchivos = []
       for (_, _, archivos) in walk(ruta):
           listaarchivos.extend(archivos)
       return listaarchivos
   ```

5. #### Usando comodines en [`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) - [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) y [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

   Para buscar archivos utilizando [comodines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) (`*`, `?`, `[seq]` y `[!seq]`)

   ```python
   from glob import glob

   def ls(expr = '*.*'):
       return glob(expr)
   ```

   Esta función devuelve la ruta completa de cada archivo.

   Ejemplo:

   ```python
   print(ls('/etc/*.conf'))
   ```

6. #### Buscar archivos con una [expresión regular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) - [python-2.2](/questions/tagged/python-2.2) y [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

   ```python
   from os import walk, getcwd, path
   import re

   def ls(regex = '', ruta = getcwd()):
       pat = re.compile(regex, re.I)
       resultado = []
       for (dir, _, archivos) in walk(ruta):
           resultado.extend([ path.join(dir,arch) for arch in 
                                 filter(pat.search, archivos) ])
           # break  # habilitar si no se busca en subdirectorios
       return resultado
   ```

   Ejemplo:

   ```python
   print(ls( r'-\d+\.[^.\d]*$', '/'))
   ```

Comment: En Python 3.4 (creo recordar) se introdujo la librería `pathlib` que no está mal conocer para todo este tipo de trabajos. Un mini tutorial aquí: http://pybonacci.org/2016/05/18/joyitas-en-la-stdlib-pathlib/

Comment: Gracias por la referencia @kikocorreoso. Lo incorporé y agregué más detalles a la respuesta.

Comment: ¡Completísima respuesta! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
def encontrar_arq(arq_buscado, camino):
    encontrado = False
    for i in camino:
        if camino == arq_buscando:
            econtrado = True
    return encontrado
```

espero que te sirva :)