# (grep -r) Buscar una cadena en cada pdf

Tags: android, python, grep, qpython

En Android 4.4.4 tengo el `terminal.apk` instalado.

¿Cómo buscar recursivamente en una tablet una cadena especifica en cada archivo pdf?

Al principio lo iba a hacer con qpython (`listdir`, `glob`), pero no me distinguía directorios de archivos para en buscar frases.

Me recomendaban algo como

```
grep -r "manzanas"
```

previa instalación de `termux/terminal.apk` y quería entender cómo utilizarlo.
..........
PYTHON : al menos previa conversion de pdf a texto y :

```
texto=input("cual texto a buscar: ")
texto2=input("2.cual otro string a buscar: ")
texto3=input("3. cual otra cadena a coincidir: ")
texto=texto.lower()
texto2=texto2.lower()
texto3=texto3.lower()
import os
mmm=[]
for (nombredir, dirs, ficheros) in os.walk('/mnt/'): 
    for nombrefichero in ficheros:
        if nombrefichero.endswith('.txt') or nombrefichero.endswith('.py') or nombrefichero.endswith(''):
                reg=nombredir+'/'+nombrefichero
                reg=reg.replace('//','/')
                arch=open(reg,'r')
                try:
                    af=arch.read()
                    af=af.lower()
                    if texto in af and texto2 in af and texto3 in af:
                      p3=nombredir
                      p2=nombrefichero
                      p1=os.path.getsize(reg)
                      tup=(p1,p2,p3)
                      mmm.append(tup)
                except (UnicodeDecodeError,IOError):
                  asd=33
                arch.close()
mmm=sorted(mmm)
a=len(range(5))
if len(mmm)<a:
    a=len(mmm)
for i in range(a):
  print(mmm[i])
```

algo pude para encontrar para encontrar hasta 3 patrones si o si y obtener un listado de los archivos.
..................
GREP
Habra que convertir online o con app pdf a texto
......
Gracias igual.

Comment: En cuanto a distinguir archivos de directorios en Python, quizás te interese leer mi respuesta en [¿Cómo listar todos los archivos de una carpeta usando Python?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24279/127). Me interesaría saber si te sirve como para seguir intentando realizarlo desde Python o si efectivamente te interesa utilizar `grep`.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es buscar un patrón en el nombre del fichero `grep` no valdría. Si lo que quieres es buscar un patrón dentro del contenido del fichero, `grep` sin el uso de otras herramientas tampoco te valdría para pdf's. Especifica un poco mejor qué es lo que quieres hacer ya que ahora mismo no está muy claro.

Comment: @Edgar como dice kikocorreoso no queda claro que quieres hacer, no es lo mismo buscar en el **nombre** de los archivos pdf que buscar dentro del **contenido** de los pdf que se encuentren en el dispositivo. El primer caso no entraña mucho problema, en el segundo necesitaras de una biblioteca para el manejo de pdf o crear tu una capaz de navegar por la estructura del pdf teniendo en cuenta las especificaciones estandar de los documentos pdf y la cosa se complica (es un formato diseñado para ser imprimido no para parsing).