# Python: ¿cómo listar todos los archivos y carpetas de una carpeta a partir de una ruta?

Tags: python

Esta pregunta se parece a esta [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24278/c%C3%B3mo-listar-todos-los-archivos-de-una-carpeta-usando-python), sin embargo es algo diferente y por ello creo que merece una respuesta aparte. Él código del que parto es el siguiente (lo he sacado de la pregunta mencionada):

```
from os import walk, getcwd

def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
     listaarchivos = []
     for (_, _, archivos) in walk(ruta):
          listaarchivos.extend(archivos)
     return listaarchivos

print(ls(ruta = getcwd()))
```

Me gustaría modificar dos cosas:

- Me gustaría que en vez de ser la ruta actual del directorio de trabajo fuera una ruta cualquiera que yo le diera, por ejemplo: C:. Si le diera esa ruta esperaría que me imprimiera una lista de todos los ficheros y carpetas de mi disco duro.
- Me gustaría que también incluyera el nombre de las carpetas que están dentro de la ruta del directorio dado así como las carpetas que se encuentran dentro de las carpetas.

[En la mencionada pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24278/c%C3%B3mo-listar-todos-los-archivos-de-una-carpeta-usando-python), el último código del punto 4 parece hacer lo que digo:

```
from os import walk, getcwd

def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
    listaarchivos = []
    for (_, _, archivos) in walk(ruta):
        listaarchivos.extend(archivos)
return listaarchivos
```

Sin embargo esto solo responde parcialmente a mi pregunta porque además necesito que aparezcan los nombres de las carpetas que están dentro de la ruta dada.

¿Cómo podría modificar el código dado para que hiciera lo que quiero?
Muchas gracias por vuestra atención.

Comment: Es duplicada, el punto [**4** de la respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24279/638) de @Mariano responde a esta pregunta. Si se escribe la ruta completa en lugar de `getcwd()` se resuelve por completo el problema.

Comment: @toledano:¿Y cómo escribo la ruta? porque he intentado poner `'c:\'` en lugar de `getcwd()` y no me sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes modificar la función que usa Mariano en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24278/c%C3%B3mo-listar-todos-los-archivos-de-una-carpeta-usando-python) para que simplemente añada los subdirectorios también:

```
from os import walk, getcwd


def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
    lista = []
    for _, subdirs, archivos in walk(ruta):
        lista.extend(subdirs+archivos)
    return lista
```

En cuanto a la ruta solo tienes que tener en cuenta que Python usa `/` propia de los sistemas Linux y no la barra inversa`\` que usa Windows:

Por ejemplo para una carpeta en windows con la ruta:

```
C:\Programacion\Python\Tkinter
```

En Python Debes cambiar todas las barras inversas por barras inclinadas (operador de división):

```
C:/Programacion/Python/Tkinter
```

Comment: La pregunta es duplicada. La respuesta es una copia de la que dio el usuario Mariano y no hay referencia a ella.

Comment: @toledano el mismo en su pregunta hace referencia a la respuesta de Mariano, yo simplemente modifico la línea `listaarchivos.extend(subdirs+archivos)` para que le guarde también los subdirectorios y aclararle lo de las rutas. De todas formas añado la referencia también aquí a la respuesta de Mariano.

Comment: @toledano FJSevilla me ha aclarado lo de las rutas

Comment: @FJSevilla tu código no debe de estar bien porque me da un error: `NameError: name 'listaarchivos' is not defined`

Comment: @Mr.Baldan Corregido, cambie el nombre de la lista al declararla pero no después... :(