# Buscar e imprimir ruta de archivo python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estimados usuarios de la comunidad StackOverflow...

busco una funcion en Python que me permita encontrar la ruta de un archivo.
por ejemplo se que tengo un programa llamado pycharm64.exe, o simplemente pycharm pero no se la ruta ... busco una funcion que busque dicho programa e imprima ruta del mismo.
De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo listar todos los archivos de una carpeta usando Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24278/127)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como muestras en tu auto-respuesta, `os.walk` es la forma multiplataforma natural de iterar recursivamente por el árbol de directorios. A partir de Python 3.5 usa internamente  `os.scandir()` en vez de `os.listdir()` lo cual mejora significativamente el tiempo de ejecución. Solo por completar un poco y mostrar como podríamos buscar ficheros que cumplan un determinado patrón:

Dado que por definición solo vamos a tener un fichero con el mismo nombre (incluida la extensión) dentro de un mismo directorio, en vez de anidar un segundo `for`, se puede usar un condicional con `in` (*membership testing*) lo cual es más eficiente.

Si no sabemos el número de ficheros con ese nombre presentes en nuestro árbol de directorios podemos usar una lista para almacenar cada una de las rutas, podemos usar listas por compresión si queremos:

```
import os

target = "programa.exe"
initial_dir = 'C:\\'

path_list = [os.path.join(root, target) for root, _, files in os.walk(initial_dir)
                                            if target in files]

print(path_list)
```

Si sabemos de antemano que solo hay un archivo con ese nombre,
es importante romper el ciclo para evitar que continúe la búsqueda
recursiva de forma innecesaria una vez encontrado el fichero (lo cual puede ahorrar recursos y un tiempo importante). De existir varios archivos retornará el primero que sea encontrado.

```
import os

target = "programa.exe"
initial_dir = 'C:\\'

path = ''
for root, _, files in os.walk(initial_dir):
    if target in files:
       path = os.path.join(root, target)
       break

print(path)
```

Si queremos buscar los archivos con un nombre dado pero con cualquier extensión (o desconocemos la extensión) podemos recurrir al módulo [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fnmatch.html) (módulo que usa *glob*) para habilitar el uso de *wildcards*:

```
import os
import fnmatch 

target = "programa.*"
initial_dir = 'C:\\'

path_list = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, _, files in os.walk(initial_dir)
                                          for file in fnmatch.filter(files, target)]

print(path_list)
```

Podemos crear otros patrones que nos permitan buscar todos los archivos con una determinada extensión, cuyo nombre empiece o termine por cierta subcadena, etc. En caso de querer buscar patrones más complejos podemos recurrir a expresiones regulares como se muestra en el punto 6 de la respuesta de Mariano a esta pregunta relacionada:

[¿Cómo listar todos los archivos de una carpeta usando Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24278/15089)

Comment: Excelente !!!

Tantisimas Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Encontré una respuesta a mi pregunta, 
dejo el resultado por si es útil para alguien mas:

```
import os


for r, d, f in os.walk("c:\\"):
    for files in f:
        if files == "programa.exe":
            print (os.path.join(r,files))
```

en caso de que **NO** tengas idea alguna de donde está el programa.

Donde:

- `r` = root
- `d` = dirs
- `f` = files

Comment: En vez de un segundo for anidado puedes usar un condicional con `in`: `target =  "programa.exe"`, `for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:\\"):`,  `if target in files:`,  `print(os.path.join(root, target))`, dado que solo vas a tener un fichero con el mismo nombre en un directorio. Si sabes que solo tienes un archivo llamado de esa forma, usa un `break` dentro del condicional para que no continúe con la búsqueda recursiva por los directorios restantes una vez encontrado. Un saludo.

Comment: me temo que esta vez no me queda del todo claro. :(

Comment: Franco tu respuesta es correcta, solo quería hacer algunas observaciones pero al no poder identar el código y a la limitación de espacio puede que no quedara claro.  He añadido una respuesta a ver si aclara lo que quería decir con el código identado correctamente.