# La ruta absoluta de un archivo en Django - Python

Tags: html, python, django

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy utilizando la librería Pydrive de python, uno de sus métodos para subir archivos me solicita la ruta absoluta del archivo y quería saber como puedo obtener esa ruta, mi código es el siguiente, utilice también os.path.abspath para obtener la ruta pero solo me da la ruta del proyecto

```
**foto = self.request.FILES['foto_can']
abs = os.path.abspath(str(foto))
print(abs)
credenciales = login()
archivo['title'] = str(foto)
archivo.SetContentFile(abs)
archivo.Upload()**
```

Salida
C:/Users/Miguel/PycharmProjects/HocicosMundo/20140312_200002.jpg

Cuando la ruta de mi archivo es c:/Users/Miguel/Pictures/20140312_200002.jpg por ejemplo

Comment: Hola jorge, bienvenido, podrías mostrarmos la ruta de tu aplicación y la de tu archivo?... 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! Cuando respondas al comentario de alguien, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado.

Comment: @MarcePuente, ......

Comment: Podrías probar con ***os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))*** para obtener la ruta del archivo, mas info [en](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python/python-get-path/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar pero sigue dándome el mismo resultado poniendo la sentencia os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Comment: Puedes mirar en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136872/buscar-e-imprimir-ruta-de-archivo-python), tal vez algo te sirva... pregunta, si introduces la ruta manualmente, funciona?.

Comment: @MarcePuente , si te cuento que si funciona cuando lo introduzco manualmente, a ver intentare este ultimo método, gracias