# Conocer que carpetas y cuantas hay dentro de otra carpeta

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero analizar elementos que se encuentran dentro de carpetas. Para ello veo que necesito emplear la librería `glob`. Googleando he aprendido a saber que elementos o cuantos hay de una extensión concreta dentro de una carpeta.

```
jpg = glob.glob('carpeta/*.jpg')
total_jpg = len(jpg)

print('Hay ',total_jpg, ' ficheros jpg')
print('Los nombres son:',jpg)
```

Pero ¿y si quisiera saber cuantas carpetas hay o los nombres de estas? No veo como hacerlo y al no tener extensión no sé como hacerlo.

Se que está este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24278/c%C3%B3mo-listar-todos-los-archivos-de-una-carpeta-usando-python) y me parece que aquí se responde pero no soy capaz de verlo, se dan un montón de opciones y no me queda claro cual hace lo que quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que `glob` se la mejor opción para analizar contenidos de carpetas. Una utilidad (en mi opinión) mejor podría basarse en `os.listdir()`, que te devuelve una lista con todos los nombres de ficheros y carpetas existentes, por lo que fácilmente puedes clasificarlos según su extensión:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

clasificados = defaultdict(list)
for nombre in os.listdir():
  if "." in nombre:
    extension = nombre.split(".")[-1].lower()
  else:
    extension = ""
  clasificados[extension].append(nombre)

for k, v in clasificados.items():
  print("Extensión '{}': {} ficheros".format(k, len(v)))
```

**Explicación**. Construimos un diccionario en el que las claves serán las extensiones de fichero, y los valores una lista con los ficheros que tienen esa extensión. La extensión se extrae partiendo con `split()` por el punto (si lo hay) y pasándola a minúsculas, y si no hay punto se pone extensión vacía. Una vez clasificados en ese diccionario, se puede recorrer para mostrar cuántos elementos hay de cada extensión. En mi caso al ejecutarlo en mi carpeta "Downloads" sale algo así:

```
Extensión 'pdf': 27 ficheros
Extensión 'zip': 1 ficheros
Extensión 'xlsx': 1 ficheros
Extensión 'png': 5 ficheros
Extensión 'py': 1 ficheros
Extensión 'gif': 3 ficheros
Extensión '': 2 ficheros
etc...
```

### Detectar directorios

Como habrás visto, lo anterior no sirve tampoco para detectar directorios, ya que no hay forma de saber por el nombre si algo es un directorio o no. Pero el módulo `os` proporciona otras formas de iterar por los contenidos de una carpeta.

Usando `os.scandir()` en lugar de obtener nombres de fichero, obtenemos *objetos* de tipo [`os.DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) con una serie de métodos que nos permiten obtener información adicional sobre cada elemento. Uno de estos métodos es `.is_dir()`, que te da `True` si es un directorio, o `.is_file()` que da `True` si es un fichero *normal*. Otro es `.name` que nos da el nombre por si queremos mirar su extensión.

Usando esto podemos clasificar por extensiones sólo a los que sean realmente ficheros, y contar aparte a los que sean directorios:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

clasificados = defaultdict(list)
directorios = []

for elemento in os.scandir():
  nombre = elemento.name
  if elemento.is_dir():
    directorios.append(nombre)
  else:
    if "." in nombre:
      extension = nombre.split(".")[-1].lower()
    else:
      extension = ""
    clasificados[extension].append(nombre)

print("{} directorios".format(len(directorios)))
for d in directorios:
  print("- {}".format(d))
print("{} ficheros".format(sum(len(caso) for caso in clasificados.values())))
for k, v in clasificados.items():
  print("- '{}': {} ficheros".format(k, len(v)))
```

Y la salida es algo como:

```
2 directorios
- Safari
- tmp
52 ficheros
- 'pdf': 27 ficheros
- 'zip': 1 ficheros
- 'xlsx': 1 ficheros
- 'png': 5 ficheros
- 'py': 1 ficheros
- 'gif': 3 ficheros
...etc
```

Comment: ¿Funciona genial, pero porque te gusta más la librería os en vez de glob? Es curiosidad por aprender a elegir bien en el futuro